# Converting Binary Search Tree to an array BFT

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, tree, heap

I'm looking to represent a binary tree as an array such that the array is in breadth first order where nulls are represented in the array. I do **not** want to use an array list but would happily use a linked list structure. I've found that the size of the max size of the array will be 2^n - 1, where n is the height of the tree for the following case :

```
            5
          /   \
        4       6
      /  \     / \
     3    x   x   7
    /\   /\  /\   /\
   x  x x x x x  x  8


[5, 4, 6, 3, null, null, 7, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 8]
```

And the least size of the array (aside from an empty tree or a root with no children [size 0 and 3 accordingly]) would be (2^n - 1) - 6, where 6 can be calculated be the number of nulls in the previous level multiplied by 2, for this case:

```
            5
          /   \
        4       6
      /  \     / \
     3    x   x   x
    /\   
   2  x 

[5, 4, 6, 3, null, null, null, 2, null]
```

Can these trees be represented like heaps where the `root` is at index 0 and the left child of the current node at index i, is 2i + 1, and the right child is 2i + 2?

Is there a recursive method for this which checks the left and right node?

Can anyone help / provide pseudo code with using only a tree and array to help implement this?

Comment: Question: what have you tried..?

Comment: @BlackPanther I have tried the heap representation option. Then queue-ing and dequeue-ing from a list and inserting them in order from the list into the array. I have only achieved all the nodes being in order, but the nulls only ending up at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a Node class and have instance variables like parent, left child, right child, value and position.

Here position is different from values, as you want to have null values to be present in your structure as you have depicted in your diagram.

Position indicates where the Node is in the tree and value represents the actual node value.

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo-code:

```
putInArray(node, index)
  array[index] = node
  if(node)
    putInArray(node->left, 2*index+1)
    putInArray(node->right, 2*index+2)
```

You can call this with putInArray(root, 0). If node is null, the method will set it the same way inside the array but won't recurse further.